# python soap api using suds: create complex variable

Tags: python-2.7, web-services, soap, suds

I am trying to write a soap client for a soap api.
I am using Pythons suds liabrary for this.
I want to create a complex variable which will give following output in soap requst:

```
<pay:idInfo>
    <api:TagValuePair>
        <api:tag>phoneNumber</<api:tag>
        <api:value>tel:+11234567890</value><api:value> 
    </api:TagValuePair>
</pay:idInfo>
```

Following is the type of idInfo:

```
>>> id_info = client.factory.create("ns0:ArrayOfTagValuePair")
>>> id_info
(ArrayOfTagValuePair){
   TagValuePair[] = <empty>
}
```

How can I add a tag and value pair in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class ArrayOfTagValuePair(suds.plugin.DocumentPlugin):
    """Plugin to add element to AccountAssignment that is not defined in WSDL."""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def parsed(self, context):
        complexTypes = context.document.getRoot().getChild('types').getChild('schema').getChildren('complexType')
        # Get the complex type with attribute 'name' == 'ArrayOfTagValuePair'.
        for ct in complexTypes:
            if ct.get('name') == 'ArrayOfTagValuePair':
                array_TagValuePair = ct

        sequenceElements = array_TagValuePair.getChild('complexContent').getChild('extension').getChild('sequence')

        for key in self.args:
            sequenceElements.append(e)


def TagValuePair(self):
    module_name = 'WS3Trans'
    service_name = 'TagValuePair'
    service_url = '%s/%s/%s.asmx?WSDL' %(self.webservice_url, module_name, service_name)
    client = suds.client.Client(service_url, plugins=[ArrayOfTagValuePair('tag', 'value')])
    return client
```

Refer the following docs [here](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.sax.element.Element-class.html) & [here](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.sax.attribute.Attribute-class.html)